# Postgresql VACUUM can't remove dead rows

Tags: postgresql, vacuum

I'm using Postgresql and I have 2 data in table.
The id values of each of the two data are 1 and 5.
[image]

Please see the picture above.
I tried `VACUUM` but dead rows are not cleaned up.

I have already tried the following ways

- Check if there are running transactions (does not exist)
- Check `autovacuum = on`
- Check read and write permissions (have permission)
- Check if table is in use by another session

I've checked everything, but running `VACUUM` doesn't clear dead rows.
I don't know how to troubleshoot.

Comment: It's a single page on disk AFAICT. What exactly are you hoping it will do? Reduce that to zero pages?

Comment: I just want to delete dead rows. I want to remove the empty space and pull the id value.

Comment: There are 0 dead rows, there is nothing to remove.

Comment: but if i run `select id from mytable` id 2, 3 and 4 do not exist. Because I deleted data 2,3,4 times.

Comment: Ok, you deleted 2, 3 and 4 and now they don't exist anymore. Vacuum also did its job, the dead tuples are gone. To me it's unclear what problem you have and how to solve it.

Comment: Oh! are you trying to get it to use "2" as the next "id" when you insert another row? That's not how sequences work - don't worry about the ID numbers, the point is that they are all different.

Comment: Please post textual details as text and not as screen captures.

Comment: I want to change the id of the data with id 5 to 2. I want to fill in the empty space. I don't want to store the new data from 2, I want to fill the empty space with the old data.

Comment: Run an update statement. But if you use a sequence or identity column for the id, this something you really don't want to do. You should never manually touch id's, there are no gabs in unique identifier. A unique number is just a number, and it's different from the other numbers. And if you don't like numbers, use a UUID

Comment: From [CREATE SEQUENCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html): *Notes ... Because nextval and setval calls are never rolled back, sequence objects cannot be used if “gapless” assignment of sequence numbers is needed. It is possible to build gapless assignment by using exclusive locking of a table containing a counter; but this solution is much more expensive than sequence objects, especially if many transactions need sequence numbers concurrently.*.

Comment: ah! i undertood. "A unique number is just a number, and it's different from the other numbers. And if you don't like numbers, use a UUID". thank you so much, i understood. I thought postgresql had a field called `__rowid__` but now I know. and now you know that `rowid` or `oid` and `id` are different